# Increase the width of a button in android

Tags: android, button

I have the following issue.

In an activity which is set up in `LANDSCAPE` mode I have a button.This magical button is set on the right side of the activity and at the bottom of the screen from my point of view.

This is how it looks like: http://i52.tinypic.com/n63rmb.png .

This is the `xml` file of my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">
      <SurfaceView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="500px">
        <Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
    android:text="Take Photo"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" 
/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the animation I do with the `button`:

```
takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
        takePhoto.setText(t);
        RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim);
          ranim.setFillAfter(true);
        takePhoto.setAnimation(ranim);
```

And finally this is `res/anim/myanim xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromDegrees="0" 
       android:toDegrees="-90"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="0" />
```

Now please tell me how to increase the `width` of that button, please.Thank you

BTW: I tried this:

```
        Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width=display.getWidth();
        height=display.getHeight();
        takePhoto.setWidth(width);
```

But there is no change at all!

Comment: how much do you want it? take all width??

Comment: in this line<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="500px">,
here why dont you change the width to some "px" instead of wrap_content

Comment: @george, sorry I did not get what you exactly trying to accomplish, do you want a button...which cover complete screen or something else ? And the code which you mentioned takePhoto.setHeight(width); in this you are setting an height and above you mentioned about width. So little confused...what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: @all I want the width of the button to covers all screen!

Comment: @Raghu I changed it because I thought that this way I could increase it.Anyway, both ways the button stays at the same size:)

Comment: @george I think the problem is in second linearLayout:
use
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="500px">
        <Button .....etc.

Comment: You can try relative layout and place linearlayouts in them..

Comment: @george Check out my new answer...hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @george it will be great if you can give me upvote...will help me in building my reputation. thanks.

Comment: I did give u an upvote;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problem in your code...first one is due to animation...comment your animation code...or change it...I run your code after commenting it out...

```
//RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim);
//ranim.setFillAfter(true);
//takePhoto.setAnimation(ranim);
```

And second problem is layout, try this layout for your R.layout.takephoto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" android:id="@+id/btnPhoto" android:text="Take Photo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<SurfaceView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnPhoto" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

One suggestion: Try to use RelativeLayout....it will simplify your layout.

Comment: But exactly like this is my layout and no effect:)

Comment: As mentioned above change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent".

Comment: And I want the width to be fill_parent only

Comment: Okay, did you tried fill_parent for your LinearLayout width ?

Comment: http://i52.tinypic.com/nlx18x.png This it how it looks with match parent.Yes I'm trying for days.I tried the impossible and still nothing happens

Comment: tried same layout...on a blank project...it looks like this...http://i52.tinypic.com/2z82006.png ....are you changing width from code somewhere ?

Comment: @george let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2162/discussion-between-gopal-and-george)

Comment: And have you used LANDSCAPE orientation for your activity?